# Add quotes to an ID in json with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

my current json output is "id":3,"name":"test", and I need the 3 to be "3".

How would I go about doing this in rails?

```
  def search
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @tags.to_json(:only => [:id, :name]) }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why do you need the `3` to be `"3"`?

Comment: another plugin is breaking because of it

Comment: What other plugin? Have you considered fixing the other plugin?

Comment: Thats my next option :/ .. its jquery-tokeinput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the only solution that worked for me:

```
  def search
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @tags.map {|t| {:id => t.id.to_s, :name => t.name }} }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sergio's solution will work. However, if you're doing this in more than one place, I would suggest overriding Rails' built in function `as_json`.

In your `Tag` model:

```
def as_json(options={})
  options[:id] = @id.to_s
  super(options)
end
```

Your controller method will remain unchanged. This is untested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
format.json do
  tags = @tags.to_json(:only => [:id, :name])
  render :json => tags.map{|t| t['id'] = t['id'].to_s; t}
end
```

Comment: When I load it, I get the error "too few arguments": app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:9:in `format'
app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:9:in `search'

Comment: Maybe error is somewhere else. I don't see error in my snippet.